# How to convert this date to Y-m-d (PHP)?

Tags: php, date

I have this date as a string: 10.21.2011, the format is mm.dd.yyyy

How can I convert this to Y-m-d? This is what I tried, but it always gives me the 1970 date.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): (about the first argument) *A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).* `mm.dd.yyy` is not in that list.

Comment: You can solve your problem even with simple string operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely because of period `.`:

```
$date = '10.21.2011';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('.', '/', $date)));
```

**Result:**

```
2011-10-21
```

Answer (score 9):

The object-oriented way:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m.j.Y', '10.21.2011');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

My opinion is that this is the approach one should try to learn with PHP.

Requires PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     $date = '10.21.2011';
> $date = strtotime(str_replace('.','/',$date));
> echo date("Y-m-d",$date);
> ```

This should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = preg_replace('/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/', '$3-$1-$2', $date);
```

Comment: @eis, above code was tested careful before posting. It works.

Comment: ah, my bad, d{2} is just there to tell that it's about two digits. Nevermind. :)